# Powershell Initiate URL XML SAVE

Tags: xml, powershell

I am a GoCanvas customer. We use apps to submit data that usually takes weeks to filter back to our business. We now have a lot of information that we can use however it is a tedious task to download CSV files

[PDF on using API](http://www.gocanvas.com/content/images/file-uploads/Canvas_Webservices.pdf)

When running the a command similar to below an XML file is returned as a webpage not a downloadable object.

https://www.gocanvas.com/apiv2/submissions?username=user@emaildomain.com.au&password=password&form_name=DD-O-FittersForm&begin_date=09/01/2015&end_date=10/01/2015

Can anyone please help me with a powershell script that will run the above URL line and then save the results as an XML file that is saved with a unique name (i assume a variable value I can enter will be ok to use?)

Thanks - Troy

Answer (score 1):

```
$source = "http://yoursite.com/file.xml"
$destination = "c:\application\data\newdata.xml"

Invoke-WebRequest $source -OutFile $destination
```

Comment: Hi Niels - thanks for the code cant believe how simple that was... thanks again.